# Why does the statement `0 < 0.5 < 1` reduce to false?

Tags: javascript, boolean

I recently discovered the [ECMAScript Spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), which I was able to use to answer a question I've had about `Math.random()` for a while; namely whether or not it would ever generate `0` without the help of `Math.floor()`.

The ECMAScript Spec specifies that `0 <= Math.random() < 1`, unlike literally anyone else for some reason. I hopped over to the console and ran a test before saving it in my notes but noticed that statement reduces to `false`.

Below is a function that tests everything about comparison statements that I thought might be causing this lie. I call the function twice to generate two arrays of Boolean values, and the results seem to imply that literally this statement: `0 <= Math.random() < 1` - and this statement alone, returns `FALSE` where it should return `TRUE`. Especially when you consider bonus round where I test the exact same statement but with an additional comparison tacked onto the end, and it also returns `true`

```js
function getTruths( a, b, c ) {
  
  return [
    
    a + 1 < b + 1,
    a + 1 < c + 1,
    b + 1 < c + 1,
    a + 1 < b + 1 < c + 1,
    
    a + 0 < b + 0,
    a + 0 < c + 0,
    b + 0 < c + 0,
    a + 0 < b + 0 < c + 0
    
  ];
  
}

function demonstrate() {
  
  // array of truth
  console.log( getTruths( 0, 1, 2 ) );
  
  // array of lies
  console.log( getTruths( 0, 0.5, 1 ) );
  
  // bonus round
  return [ 0 < 0.5 < 1 < 1.5 ];
  
}

demonstrate();
```

So I did some more plucking around and learned that it isn't just that. it seems that `a` and `b` can actually be any value lower that one and equal to or greater than zero, just as long as `b` is still bigger than `a`, and `c` is still equal to `1` of course... and given those parameters, no matter what, the return is still `FALSE`. If you add `1` to everything though suddenly you're in good shape again, just as in the function provided above.

Anyway can someone explain this to me? Thanks.

Comment: Grouping `<` and `>` comparisons like that does not do what one might think it does.

Comment: *The ECMAScript Spec specifies that 0 <= Math.random() < 1, unlike literally anyone else for some reason.* Well, that is just saying that a random will be >=0 and < 1 and that's pretty common for random generation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a < b < c
```

is interpreted as

```
(a < b) < c
```

The result value from a relational operator like `<` is a boolean, either true or false.  If `c` is a number, then, that boolean will be converted to a number, either 1 (`true`) or 0 (`false`).  Thus `c` is compared to either 0 or 1, not the values of either `a` or `b`.

The proper way to write "is `b` strictly between `a` and `c`" is

```
a < b && b < c
```

Comment: so if `1 < 1.5` is `true`, and `true < 2` is `true`, then `2`.... Okay I think I got it.

Comment: @Musixauce3000 yes that's exactly it. JavaScript algebraic and comparison operators are all "left and right" two-operand operators, so they're always grouped like that.

Comment: and that's why `0 < 0.5 < 1 < 1.5` returns `true` too... because it goes one at a time, eg: `true < 1` is `false` so `false < 1.5` is `true`